# jquery - select elements that match one of the following classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to improve performance of my script. I want to improve this:

```
el.removeClass( classes ).css( "top", 
  ( ( el.is(".ui-fixed") || 
        el.is( ".ui-global" ) || 
          el.is( ".ui-element" ) 
          ) && thisCSStop > 0 ) ? -9999 : 0 );
```

Isn't it possible to combine

```
el.is(".ui-fixed") || el.is( ".ui-global" ) ||  el.is( ".ui-element")
```

into a single statement like so:

```
el.is("one or two or three");
```

I can't get it to work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
el.is(".ui-fixed,.ui-global,.ui-element")
```